# Analog filter resistors and capacitor tradeoffs

Tags: analog, filter, design, active-filter

I am designing a filter to obtain a dc reference from a signal, and I am thinking about using the schematic below for a cutting frequency of 1 Hz:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZT8i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question is: how much can I increase R1 and C1 to lower the cutoff frequency? 
 
Theoretically I could put there a resistance of 1 MΩ, but what are the drawbacks  (apart from the settling time) in increasing R1 (or C1) indefinitely?

Comment: I've certainly made ~100 second time constant's with 10 Meg and 10 uF, but you have to wait a long time then to get to your correct DC value.  At some point you can't wait that long.. and then a double pole filter will help.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it and reading the answers I am already thinking about using a Sallen-Key instead of that.

Comment: You can just cascade two of the above opamp buffered low passes too.  It's an extra opamp...

Comment: I am afraid, a Sallen-Key topolgy (2nd-order) will not simplify the general problem: Large time constants for low pole frequencies. Perhaps you are intersetd to use a capacitance multiplier (if you can afford two additional opamps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL081 is a FET input opamp, so you can increase your R1 to Mohms before you run into serious voltage voltage problems due to bias current. You will probably have more trouble from board surface leakage, moisture and dust on fingerprints etc, before bias currents from that particular amplifier.

Capacitor leakage is generally not a problem if you avoid electrolytics.

However if the purpose of increasing the R and C is to filter the DC reference heavily, you may be better off building a higher order filter. You can go up to 3rd order Sallen Key, and still stay with one unity gain opamp.

Answer (score 2):

Every opamp has an input bias current specification. This bias current introduces a DC voltage error proportional to R1.

So as part of your error budget, you set an allowable error voltage from this cause, read the worst case bias current from the datasheet, and now Ohm's Law gives you an upper bound on R1's value.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the values of R1 and C1 as much as you like BUT at some point parasitic components will come into play. For example: suppose the opamp has a 10 Mohm input resistance then what will happen if R1 is also 10 Mohm ? Large value capacitors usually have more leakage in the form of a parallel resistor. What if this resistor was 10 Mohm ? You have to consider what are practical values for R1 and C1 without the parasitic components interfering too much.

Comment: There was no Question 1, that line was just the introduction to Question 2. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: OK, was reading too fast ;-)